# A Q on powershell string split()

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I did the scripting like

```
$item_name = $item["Server_Name"]
$result = nslookup $item_name #a nslookup code to get the server's ip
$split = $result.tostring()
```

Caz use split() directly will fail, so I used to String(), but it display like System.Object[]

how can I exact the content from the $result

Answer (score 0):

Invoking an executable and storing the result in a variable will give you the standard output in a string *array* corresponding to the "lines" of output.

In general, if you want to combine the elements of a string array into a single string, use `-join <delimiter>`.  As in

```
'one','two','three' -join 'xyz'
'one','two','three' -join "`r`n"
```

So you could do

```
$result = nslookup <servername>
$singleString = $result -join "`r`n"
<process $singleString here>
```

Or, if you are searching for a particular string pattern in the output, I like to use this pattern, which handles each line of output individually:

```
nslookup <server> |?{ $_ -match 'someregex' } |%{ <use $matches here to process> }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using `-join` for taking an array of strings and creating a single string, you can simply pipe the output of nslookup to `Out-String` e.g.:

```
$result = nslookup $server_name | Out-String
```